# Intensity Of Sound

Tags: waves, acoustics

I know that intensity of sound at a distance 'r' from the the source of sound is given by the equation (i) in the image. Also the second equation gives the wave intensity, **but at what point or distance from the source this intensity is??**
*As we can see the every term in the equation (ii) remains constant and not change with the distance.[image]

Comment: What are the variables inside the brackets in your second equation?

Comment: 'V' is velocity of the wave in the medium,  'w2' is the angular velocity of wave and the that remaining one is the density of given medium.

Comment: In that case the $r^{-2}$ dependence is in $S_m$ i.e. $S_m = S_0/r^2$ for some constant $S_0$.

Comment: from your conclusion, $Sm=S0/r^2$, i.e.  we can say that amplitude Sm is inversely proportional to square of distance from source. but we know intensity (I) is directly proportional to square of amplitude ($Sm^2$) and also from my first equation (I) is inversely proportional to ($r^2$). from these two we get $Sm^2$ is inversely proportional to $r^2$  i.e Sm is inversely proportional to r, which is against your conclusion that Sm is inversely proportional to $r^2$. Please explain

Comment: I just want to know that if you have been given all numerical values of all variables in the equation (ii). Example value of each variable in equation (ii) is 1 and you are asked to find out intensity of wave at a distance of 5m from the source using equation (ii) then how will you find it.